# Using C# & Xamarin Forms - How can I close one modal without setting of chain of closures

Tags: c#, android, ios, navigation, xamarin.forms

In one stage of my app (Android & iOS are the ones we care about) we've got three pages which take in details and then open a webView for the user to input their card details to take a payment - this can't be done in the app due to Apple's guidelines.

I need to format the navigation in a way that when the user has finished in the webView it closes and then closes the 3 previous modals to get back to the original page. I've got it all working with the Appearing event so each page just closes itself:

```
this.Appearing += async (s, e) =>
{
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
};
```

The issue I'm now having is that when the user presses the back button on the phone, it closes all of the pages that they've been through already & back to the original. I thought about implementing a custom nav bar and disabling the back button on the hardware but this would cause the same problem with the Appearing event.

Is there any easy way to solve this?

EDIT: Relevant code;

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            var button = (Button) sender;
            button .IsEnabled = false;
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page());
            this.Appearing += (s, e) =>
            {
                ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                button.IsEnabled = true;
                RefreshPage();
            };
        }
        else
        {
            NoInternetLabel.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by using Actions. In each new Page() we passed up an async method to close it once the one after had completed;

```
var nextPage = new Page(async () => 
{ 
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync(); 
    _completedSuccessfully();
});
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(nextPage);
```

And in the new page class;

```
private readonly Action _completedSuccessfully;
public Page(Action completedSuccessfully)
{        
    _completedSuccessfully = completedSuccessfully;
}
```

This meant that when the webView closed it called the completedSuccessfully() action and then chained all of them to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
YourButton.Clicked += OpenPage;
```

OpenPage looks like this:

```
async public void OpenPage(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageToShow());
}
```

You don't have to do anything to handle the `PageToShow()` closing, that happens by itself when the user presses the back button.

Comment: Already using that; await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page());
Not sure how that helps with the closing of pages?

Comment: Can you add the all of the code that does this? For example, is the method that contains that line `async`? I use this exact code (var names changed) and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: It comes from the button;
OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (connectedToInternet)
    {
        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(newPage());
        this.Appearing += (s, e) =>
                {
                    ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                    RefreshCommand();
                };
    }
}

Comment: Can you update your question to contain all of the relevant code?

Comment: Also, if it is worth noting, my `PageToShow()` inherits from `ContentPage`

Comment: Updated Q. My `new Page()` also inherits from `ContentPage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130230/discussion-between-ninjafocks-and-sam).